Integration with a random variable
How to approach this integral:
$I(t) =  e^{\int j A \cos(\alpha t + \phi (t))dt}$ where $A$ and $\alpha$ are constant and $j = \sqrt{-1}$
$\phi (t)$ is modelled as a Wiener process (Gaussian distributed
random variable with a variance of $\sigma^2 $ and zero mean). I have never integrated anything with a random variable inside the integral. However, from what I can gather on the internet, it involves dealing with expectation value. Any help will be highly appreciated.

So, for each $t$, we have $\phi(t)$ is a random variable?  That seems strange.
